# How to implement a nested list, and call the nested sub-list in the widget build?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a model class'ServicesCategory', which nests a 'subCategory'. I created a 'categoryList' as below.
I passed the ServiceCategory object in the Navigator to the CategoryDetailsView page.
Although, navigation works accurately while passing the properties of the 'categoryList' in the AppBar and the ListView.builder here in the example, but the issue is:

1. For categoryId '01', when navigating to 'Facility', the sub-categories are correctly built in the CategoryDetailsView page
   (i.e., categoryId '01' and subCategoryId '01').
2. But for the categoryId '02', when navigating to 'Notice Board', the same sub-categories from categoryId '01' are built in the CategoryDetailsView page, instead of the (i.e., categoryId '02' and subCategoryId '01').

Hope I have explained this to the best of my ability, and your help is highly appreciated.

Also, your suggestion to improve my naive implementation will be of great help, thanks.

#### categoryList

```
List<ServicesCategory> categoryList = [
  ServicesCategory(
    categoryId: '01',
    name: 'Facility',
    description: 'description',
    image: 'image',
    icon: const Icon(Icons.deck),
    iconSize: iconSize,
    subCategory: [
      SubCategory(
        subCategoryId: '01',
        categoryId: '01',
        name: 'Function Hall',
        description: '''
        This function hall is equipped with a seating capacity of 30.
        ''',
        image: 'image',
        icon: const Icon(Icons.party_mode_outlined),
      ),
      // ... (other subcategories for categoryId '01')
    ],
  ),
  ServicesCategory(
    categoryId: '02',
    name: 'Notice Board',
    description: 'description',
    image: 'image',
    icon: const Icon(Icons.assignment_outlined),
    iconSize: iconSize,
    subCategory: [
      SubCategory(
        categoryId: '02',
        subCategoryId: '01',
        name: 'Maintenance Activity',
        description: '''
        Fogging is every Monday & Thursday.
        ''',
        image: 'image',
        icon: const Icon(Icons.party_mode_outlined),
      ),
      // ... (other subcategories for categoryId '02')
    ],
  ),
];
```

#### Passing the ServicesCategory object in the Navigation from the HomeView page

```
Widget buildCategoryGrid({required Color bgColor}) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 8,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3 ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            // Instance of the categoryList
            ServicesCategory servicesCategory = categoryList[index];

            return GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
               
                child: GridTile(
                  footer: Container(                    
                    child: Wrap(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          servicesCategory.name,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: Theme.of(context)                         
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: servicesCategory.icon != null
                      ? Icon(
                          servicesCategory.icon!.icon,
                          size: 50,
                        )
                      : const Icon(
                          Icons.broken_image,
                          size: 50,
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              '''
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      // Passing the object
                      return CategoryDetailsView(
                        servicesCategory: servicesCategory,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              '''
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### Implementation of the nested-list in the widget build.

```
class CategoryDetailsView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryDetailsView({
    super.key,
    required this.servicesCategory,
  });

  final ServicesCategory servicesCategory;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
    // Calling the name property of the servicesCategory object.
          title: Text(servicesCategory.name),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(

          itemCount: servicesCategory.subCategory.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {

        // Create an instance of the subCategory
            SubCategory subCategory = subCategoryList[index];

            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListTile(                 
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    child: subCategory.icon,
                  ),
                  title: Text(subCategory.name),
                  subtitle: Text(subCategory.description),
                  trailing: IconButton(                   
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month_outlined),
                  ),
               ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your code exactly as you posted here? do you have `subList`s as a seperate global variable somewhere in your code? Otherwise the code must break at `Create an instance of the subCategory` beacause `subCategoryList[index]` is undefined and it should be like `SubCategory subCategory = servicesCategory.subCategory[index];`

Comment: Yes, the is the same as posted, but with more categories, and sub-categories. The solution did work, thanks. However, is it the best practice to keep the categories & sub-categories separate instead?

Comment: I had kept the sub-category separate but was unable to use it in the categoryList.(subCategory: []; This is how I used it while creating the ServicesCategory object )

Comment: I just asked that because you don't have any `subCategoryList` variable. If you have all the sublists for all the categories in a seperate variable (for example for the learning purposes, or mocking backend server and you want to fetch subcategories from server later when user navigate to subpage), you must search for the correct subcatogories with `id == category.id` in your list and you should do something like `subCategory[0]` beacause it always returns the same thing.